# Glsl artifacts after fract uv coords

Tags: opengl, glsl

I am trying to make a grid with fragment shader and i get problems with uv coords.

On this screenshot you can see first result:
[image]

```
float roundRect(vec2 p, vec2 size, float radius) {
    vec2 d = abs(p) - size;
    return min(max(d.x, d.y), 0.0) + length(max(d, 0.0)) - radius;
}

void main() {
    vec2 uv = gl_FragCoord.xy / u_resolution.xy;
    
    vec2 f_uv = fract(uv * 22.680);
    
    float rect = smoothstep(0.040, 0.0, roundRect(f_uv - vec2(0.5), vec2(0.44), 0.040));

    gl_FragColor = vec4(vec3(rect), 1.0);
}
```

Second:

[image]

```
float roundRect(vec2 p, vec2 size, float radius) {
    vec2 d = abs(p) - size;
    return min(max(d.x, d.y), 0.0) + length(max(d, 0.0)) - radius;
}

void main() {
    vec2 uv = gl_FragCoord.xy / u_resolution.xy;
    
    vec2 f_uv = fract(uv * 20.680);
    
    float rect = smoothstep(0.040, 0.0, roundRect(f_uv - vec2(0.5), vec2(0.44), 0.040));

    gl_FragColor = vec4(vec3(rect), 1.0);
}
```

These both screenshots have a difference in line

```
vec2 f_uv = fract(uv * x);
```

How can i fix it?

Comment: @Rabbid76 Sorry. I have deleted screenshots of the code

Comment: You should describe the problem as well as showing screenshot, it's not immediately clear that anything is wron based on these images. Basically, what do you expect to see?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you see is aliasing caused by gridlines

- thinner than the pixels themselves, and
- spaced at non-integer pixel intervals.

To fix that you need to [band-limit your function](https://iquilezles.org/www/articles/bandlimiting/bandlimiting.htm). One way of doing this is as follows:

```
void main() {
    float scale = 22.680;
    vec2 uv = gl_FragCoord.xy / u_resolution.xy * scale;
    float fw = max(fwidth(uv.x), fwidth(uv.y));
    float rect = smoothstep(fw, -fw, roundRect(fract(uv) - vec2(0.5), vec2(0.44), 0.040));

    gl_FragColor = vec4(vec3(rect), 1.0);
}
```

The results look as follows:

[image]

Note that some lines are still blurrier than others -- but the only way around it is to ensure that your scale factor is an integer amount of pixels.